# Different about including Drive API library between using Google Eclipse Plugin automatically and add .jar files manually

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I used to add Google Drive API v2 in my project by using Google Eclipse Plugin, it successful.(automatically)

But when I add all libraries by downloading [google-api-services-drive-v2-rev89-java-1.15.0-rc.zip](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) at **Drive API** index, and including my project : **Add into /libs; Add jar in Java Build Path; Checked in Order and Export** (manually).

The **error** show here :

`import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;`

`import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;`

*(it means can not import GenericUrl.java and HttpResponse.java class)*

And the **error**

`The type com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

*(it means AbstractGoogleJsonClient not exists)*

show in here :
`HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                        .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                        .execute();`

Please tell me how to fix,

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to manually add jar files? Was there any problem with Drive API added by Google Plugin?

Comment: Yes, eclipse get stuck (not responding)  many times when installed Google Eclipse Plugin, the error show here "Android SDK: Resolving error markers". Therefore, i want to restrict it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractGoogleJsonClient` is in `google-api-client-<version>.jar`, there is a fundamental problem with your classpath if it's not found.

Comment: @AlexTran How you fix this ? Please explain ? I cannot see anything

Comment: You know how to set up Environment? Create new Attribute CLASS_PATH at there, define the file path of this jar file.It means the Class need environment to run.